# Express return 3 times responses

Tags: node.js, rest, express

When I send a request to rest API, I get 3 response. One of them, my response but another responses are favicon and robot.txt responses.

my server.js file is :

```
const http = require('http');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = require('./app');

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

and my app.js file is :

```
    const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');


app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'It works!'
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

And when I send request to localhost:3000
my console logs like that:

```
GET / 200 5.395 ms - 23
GET /robots.txt?1608151923845 200 0.472 ms - 23
GET /favicon.ico 200 0.472 ms - 23
```

Why I getting this responses?

Comment: Your browser is requesting them. The browser, unlike non-browser software like Postman or curl or wget, is designed primarily for the user experience. This means the browser will always try to detect if you have a mini page icon (displayed in the tab). It does this by always trying to get a file called favicon.ico (or other icon file declared in your html's metadata if you have any). It will do this even if you, the server owner, don't want to because the browser was designed for the user, not you and users like to see pretty icons in tabs

Comment: The robots.txt file is normally not requested by browsers. Instead they are normally downloaded by web crawlers such as Google or Bing to find out if you allow them to crawl and index your website (so people can search your website on Google or Bing) or if you want to ban them. Nice crawlers will try to find out your intent by reading your robots.txt file if you have any. Bad crawlers ignore the robots.txt file